# Navigation items are hidden in Device 4s and working in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have designed the app and its working in devices, 5s, ipad and all simulators. But unfortunately when I tested in Device 4s then the navigation items is not displayed.

Can anyone help.

Left menu added from storybard and drop down function code is as follows:-

```
    UIImageView *menu =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 12, 25, 15)];
    [menu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"options.png"]];
    lblGroupName=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 5, 150, 25)];
    [lblGroupName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"50"]];
    lblGroupName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    [lblGroupName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [lblGroupName setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [lblGroupName setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIButton *actionBtn =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [actionBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loadOptionTableView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [actionBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 135, 35)];
    actionBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIView *rightBarButtonItems = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 35)];
    [rightBarButtonItems addSubview:lblGroupName];
    [rightBarButtonItems addSubview:menu];
    [rightBarButtonItems addSubview:actionBtn];

    self.navigationItem.titleView =rightBarButtonItems;
```

Scree Desired

[image]

Screen Displayed in Device 4S IOS 7.1

[image]

Comment: Can you attach screen shot of these?

Comment: Have you incorporated Auto-Layout correctly... ??

Comment: Screen shot in simulator 4s is attached and the navigation bar is displayed in the device but the menu items are not displayed.

Comment: also add screen for expected results & constraints @ CJ IOS Developer

Comment: The screen shot is for expected results which is working in 5 s and all the simulators but not working in device 4s where OS 7.1. Is is OS related issue or any other.

Comment: You have not attached any new image.

Comment: Please see question image is uploaded.

Comment: Please show your code also.

Comment: @Nirmit please see the updated image where navigation left menus item not displayed.